# Python YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fff-zz:xx formatted datetime issue

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-dateutil

I am in a really weird problem. I am cleaning a dataset that contains a lot of ISO formatted datetime object. However, a lot of them are throwing errors. Let me clarify them with an example:

Example 1: `date_str1 = '2019-09-18T07:52:53.167-04:00` . I used `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_str1)` on it and that works.

Example 2: `date_str2 = 2019-09-18T07:52:50.69-04:00` . I used `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_str2)` on it and that does not work.

Example 3:  `date_str2 = 2019-09-18T07:52:50.690-04:00` . I used `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_str2)` on it and that works.

Apparently, if the seconds value has 3 digit after the decimal points, it works. If there are any less it does not work which is odd because syntactically they are same.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: `2019-09-18T07:52:50.69-04:00` wouldn't be the same as `2019-09-18T07:52:50.690-04:00` would it? It would surely need a `zfill` and become `069` not `690`. In any case, I've not experienced this before; are you sure the issue isn't upstream in how the datetime is saved?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally. I needed to use the `strptime()` function for it. The code snippet that worked is: `dt.datetime.strptime(date_str2,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')`. Note two things:

- The timezone should be lowercase z, not uppercase.
- You need to account for fractional seconds by adding `%f` in the representation string.